# creating a sbt plugin that uses a Key from another plugin and avoiding cycle

Tags: sbt, sbt-native-packager

I am working on the play2-war-plugin: https://github.com/dlecan/play2-war-plugin

After the migration to play 2.2, the war plugin is using the key `com.typesafe.sbt.packager.Keys.projectDependencyArtifacts` from the native package plugin, to find out the list from jars to include in the generated war:

https://github.com/dlecan/play2-war-plugin/blob/develop/project-code/plugin/src/main/scala/com/github/play2war/plugin/Play2WarCommands.scala#L51

With this change, a dependency was introduced to the native package plugin.

With this new dependency, it is now imppossible to add the `war` command to the `package` task, as the `package` task depends on the native package plugin. This creates a cycle.
https://github.com/dlecan/play2-war-plugin/blob/develop/project-code/plugin/src/main/scala/com/github/play2war/plugin/Play2WarSettings.scala#L59

This problem is tracked in the [issue 198](https://github.com/dlecan/play2-war-plugin/issues/198)

My question:
is it possible to fix that situation? Is there any workaround?